# Copy clicked li html into another tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle action" data-toggle="dropdown">Nav name <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul id="nav" class="dropdown-menu test">
    <li><a href="#" id="action-1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="action-2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="action-3">three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a `<li>` is clicked I need the HTML of the list tag to replace "Nav name"

This is the jQuery i'm using and a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/pLGnU/7/)

```
jQuery("#action-1").click(function(e){
 jQuery('.action').html('one <span class="caret"></span>');
e.preventDefault();
});
jQuery("#action-2").click(function(e){
 jQuery('.action').html('two <span class="caret"></span>');
e.preventDefault();
});
jQuery("#action-3").click(function(e){
 jQuery('.action').html('three <span class="caret"></span>');
e.preventDefault();
});
```

This isn't clean code I know and it can be written better. How can I use $this with jQuery to get the HTML of the li tag and replace the .action class html which is "Nav name"? Since the drop down list is going to be generated dynamically I need to use a method to get the HTML of the li clicked but not sure how to write it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#nav > li > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".action").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.action').html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ExBjf/1/)